# Google Cloud Print API - white page when printing PDF

Tags: node.js, pdf, google-cloud-print, unirest

I want to send a PDF file to be printed using the Google Cloud Print API. The code bellow will give me a positive message telling me that one page was generate. When I go and check what came out, I gate an empty page.

The same result happens if I save the print on Google Drive.

## The code

```
unirest.post('https://www.google.com/cloudprint/submit')
.header('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + token)
.header("Accept-Charset", "utf-8")
.field('xsrf', xsrf_token)
.field('printerid', printerId)
.field('ticket', '{"version": "1.0", "print": {}}')
.field('title', 'Test from Simpe.li')
.field('contentType', 'application/pdf')
.attach('content', buffer)
.end(function (res) {

    console.log(res);

});
```

I know that what I'm sending is a PDF, because when I change the

```
.field('contentType', 'application/pdf')
```

to

```
.field('contentType', 'text/plain')
```

I will get 53 pages of text which is the raw content of the PDF file.

[image]

## Question

What I'm doing wrong?

## Tech spec

- NodeJS v4.1.1
- Unirest v0.4.2

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It turns out that the Google documentation left some key information out. To send a binary type data, like a PDF, you need to convert the file to base64. In addition to that you need to tell Google that you are going to send them a base64 blob with the add field `contentTransferEncoding` and set the value to `base64`.

Another important thing. There is a bug in `Unirest` (for NodeJS at least), where sending a base64 file won't set the `Content-Size` header. Nor even setting your own will fix the problem. To circumvent this issue I had to switch to [Request](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request). The following code shows a post to Google Cloud Print that works:

```
let buffer64 = buffer.toString('base64');

let formData = {
    xsrf: xsrf_token,
    printerid: printerId,
    ticket: '{"version": "1.0"}',
    title: 'Test Print',
    contentTransferEncoding: 'base64',
    contentType: 'application/pdf',
    content: buffer64
};

let headersData = {
    'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token
};

request.post({
    url: 'https://www.google.com/cloudprint/submit',
    headers: headersData,
    formData: formData
}, function (err, httpResponse, body) {

  if (err) {

    return console.error('upload failed:', err);

  }

  console.log('Upload successful!  Server responded with:', body);

});
```

I hope this will help others :)

Comment: Where did you get your token in headersData? Is that something the user has to authenticate for?

Comment: If you are talking about OAuth 2.0, then you should read this https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2 to find out how it works.

Comment: Ok, I was hoping there was a way to use google cloud printing without authenticating users. Like, if there was a way to print to one designated printer silently and without user involvement.

Comment:  no man, no body would want their printer to randomly start printing :D

Comment: Lol, not what I meant though. I'm working with a restaurant and I'd like to print to their printer using google cloud print when users order food from my app.

Comment: Then just add supper for Auth2.0, and let them authenticate from your app with Google, so they can give you access to their printers :) no problemo :)

Comment: Would it be ok for me to pm you?

Comment: Yes, no problem

Comment: Ok, I can't seem to export this conversation to chat so I'll just try to explain here. The restaurant I'm working with has a printer in their brick and mortar building. So when a user makes a purchase on the app, we're using square as a payment processor, I'd like to use google cloud print to send a job to that printer in the restaurant itself. Using google cloud print though you seem to need the user using the app to sign in to google first and that wouldn't make any sense in the flow of the app.

Comment: Since this is a separate questions, create a question on stack, and send the link to https://twitter.com/dawidgatti, and I'll give you a nice response :) I can't do it in this section, not enough space.

Comment: Ok, I've sent it :)

Comment: Or you can use an headless browser to authenticate to google and retrieve the access token.